# Exponential Function and Integral

Tags: integration, exponential-function, riemann-integration

For any fixed $x>0$, find the value
$$
\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{x} \exp \left(-k t^{2} / 2\right) dt.
$$

From the first sight, it seems that the function $f_k(t) = \exp(-k t^{2} / 2)$ will be uniformly convergent to some function $f_0$, which will guarantee the result of the suggested problem. However, this seems to be a little bit challenging to determine the exact value for $f_0$. Are there any ideas on the intuition behind determining such $f_0$ functions from the very beginning?!

Comment: For any real $x$, $$\left| \int_0^x e^{-kt^2/2}\,dt\right|\le \int_0^\infty e^{-kt^2/2}\,dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2k}}$$Now squeeze.

Comment: Could you please derive the RHS inequality? It seems a little bit non-rigorous to me in terms of purely mathematical way.

Comment: @Snowflake: Without deriving the precise equality, a change of variable $u = \sqrt{k}t$ in the integral shows that $\int_0^\infty e^{-kt^2/2}\,dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2/2}\,du$, which is proportional to $1/\sqrt{k}$, which is enough to apply the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: Hmm, where then the $\pi$ will appear in the inequality?

Comment: @Snowflake The integrand is positive.  So the integral as a function of $x$ is increasing.  That is rigorous!

Comment: @Snowflake: We have a lower bound of $0$ because everything is positive. Mark Viola showed an upper bound of the form $C/\sqrt{k}$. Since $C/\sqrt{k}\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$, $\int_0^x e^{-kt^2/2}\,dt \to 0$ as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Oh, now I see the true application of the squeeze theorem. By the way, what is the name of the theorem that suggests that the integral could be written as some constant value $C$? Is there any specific result deriving the above fact?

Comment: @Snowflake: If you agree with the change of variables, then the integral next to $1/\sqrt{k}$ is just a number $C$ independent of $k$ if you agree it is finite, without necessary knowing its exact value.

Comment: Precisely, that was the thing that drove my curiosity: how could we prove that the improper integral is just constant value (actually, the finiteness of this improper integral)? Should we bring up the limits to showcase this property, or this is derived from the famous rules?

Comment: @Snowflake: You can bound $e^{-t^2/2}$ by say $10e^{-t}$ for large $t$, and then the integral is explicitly computable. Also if you search "Gaussian integral" on this site, you can find detailed explanations of how to compute the value precisely. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to get you started: $f_k(t)\to 0$ uniformly for $t\in [0.1,x]$. Since $\int_0^x = \int_0^{0.1} + \int_{0.1}^x$, we have $$\limsup_{k\to\infty}\int_0^x f_k(t)\,dt \le 0.1.$$

Comment: I guess we could substitute the $0.1$ value with any $\epsilon$ larger than $0$, and obtain the desired value being smaller than $\epsilon$ for any choice of $\epsilon > 0$; thus, the suggested answer turns out to be identically zero.

Comment: Does this ending correctly been concluded!?

Comment: @Snowflake: That's correct. The key point is that for any $\epsilon$, the convergence on $[\epsilon,x]$ will be uniform, in spite of the fact that the convergence on $[0,x]$ is not uniform.

Comment: Now, one question popped up whenever was writing it explicitly: Due to the uniform convergence to zero, the desired integral will be equivalent to  $$\limsup_{k\to\infty}\int_0^\epsilon f_k(t)\,dt$$
How is it possible to derive the fact that this value is less than $\epsilon$?

Comment: For any real $x$, $$\left| \int_0^x e^{-kt^2/2}\,dt\right|\le \int_0^\infty e^{-kt^2/2}\,dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2k}}$$Now squeeze.

Comment: @Snowflake: Try finding some simple upper bound $B$ for $f_k(t)$ and replace $f_k(t)$ by $B$ in the integral $\int_0^\epsilon$. The bound $B$ doesn't need to depend on $k$ because $\epsilon$ is already doing the job of making this term small.